# How does OneSignal "OnePush" internally works

Tags: onesignal

I looking to integrate OneSignal for Push notification. But I thought of reading about OneSignal to understand how it works.

After reading through the following article [Rust at OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/blog/rust-at-onesignal/) . I seem to me that OneSignal internally used HTTP to send push notification to device as oppose to a wrapper over FCM.

How does this work ?

Does that means for ever device (running OneSignal SDK) has a HTTP connection opened with OneSignal.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of push itself, OneSignal works by connecting to Apple and Google's push servers. Any time a push is sent (via the OneSignal dash or the REST API) OneSignal notifies the push servers. OnePush is the main delivery engine for those requests. Once the respective push servers receive the request from OneSignal, they send notifications to the individual devices.